# How can I specify arguments in the middle of the sentence in gherkin-style tests in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework, gherkin

Using Robot Framework, I am intent on using Gherkin style tests since it is the lingua franca of BDD/ATDD. I can specify a test like this:

```
*** Test Cases ***
New alert
    Given there were no alerts so far
    When there is an alert
    Then an alert should be sent with level  LOW
```

and Robot will map this to methods in my test library without any help:

```
def there_were_no_alerts_so_far(self):
    assert(self.alert == None)

def there_is_an_alert(self):
    self.alert = self.alert_processor.alert()

def an_alert_should_be_sent_with_level(self, level):
    assert_not_none(self.alert )
    assert_equal(self.alert.level.name, level )
```

Cool. I can pass a parameter like `level` to the test library.

But what I don't know how to do, is specify a parameter which is in the middle of the clause, as in:

```
There there are 5 alerts sent
```

which I would like to map to this method in the test library:

```
def there_is_an_alert_after_seconds(self, seconds):
...
```

In this case the `5` is in the middle of the clause.
In pytest.bdd there are decorators in the test library that you can use to specify how to parse the clause.
What is the equivalent in robot?

I tried this but to no avail:

```
*** Keywords ***
there is an alert after ${time} seconds
    there is an alert after seconds ${time}
```

Answer (score 4):

The robot framework user guide has a section that covers how to do this. See [Embedding arguments into keyword name](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#embedded-argument-syntax)

### User keywords

It's very simple with user keywords: instead of using `[Arguments]` you merely embed the variable references in the keyword name. This is the example given in the user guide:

```
 *** Keywords ***
 Select ${animal} from list
    Open Page    Pet Selection
    Select Item From List    animal_list    ${animal}
```

You use this keyword like you would expect:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Example
    Select Dog from list
```

### Library Keywords

You can also do this with keywords written in python by using the [keyword decorator](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-decorators) provided by robot.  For example:

```
from robot.api.deco import keyword
@keyword('Select ${animal} from list')
def select_animal_from_list(animal):
    ...
```

### Using quotes

While not strictly necessary, it's considered good practice to surround the argument with quotes. The example given in the user guide is this:

```
Select ${city} ${team}
```

If you call this with `Select Los Angeles Lakers`, how will robot know if `${city}` should match "Los" or "Los Angeles"? Placing quotes around it will solve that problem:

```
Select "${city}" "${team}"
```

Of course, that means you also have to supply quotes when calling the keyword:

```
   Select "Los Angeles" "Lakers"
```

### Other features

It's also possible to use regular expressions to match arguments. For a comprehensive description of how to do that, see the user guide.

Answer (score 0):

This keywords-section "rule" does the trick.
Robot is very nit-picky about the format.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Second alert soon after, first escalation
    Given there is an alert
    When there is an alert after "7" seconds
```

Note that the variable should be quoted.

```
*** Keywords ***
there is an alert after "${time}" seconds
    there is an alert after seconds  ${time}
```

The variable should be in quotes in the rule (first line), and preceded by 2 spaces in the value (second line).

This maps successfully to:

```
def there_is_an_alert_after_seconds(self, seconds):
    ...
```

Comment: There is no requirement for the embedded argument to be in quotes; that is just a recommendation, for the reason Bryan Oakley explains in his answer. Robot was nit-picky in the case you cited, because you had two keywords with virtually the same signature; by adding the quotes, the signature of the first changed. In fact, if the first one was named `there's an alert after ${time} seconds`  - a simple grammatical change, and the second one remained as is, RF would happily swallow and process them.