# Infix arguments keyword in python

Tags: python, robotframework

I want to write keyword with infix arguments in python, is it possible?

```
*** Keywords ***
Set ${var} on device
    set samething on device  samething=${var}
```

Can I write Set ${var} on device in python?

Comment: Can you elaborate, what is the point of asking a question that is addressed clearly in the public documentation, and answering it yourself 5 minutes later? It also has been asked before on SO - [more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44845765/3446126).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I specify arguments in the middle of the sentence in gherkin-style tests in robot framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44844567/how-can-i-specify-arguments-in-the-middle-of-the-sentence-in-gherkin-style-tests)

Answer (score 1):

```
from robot.api.deco import keyword

@keyword('Add ${quantity:\d+} Copies Of ${item} To Cart')
def add_copies_to_cart(quantity, item):
    # ...
*** Test Cases ***
My Test
    Add 7 Copies Of Coffee To Cart
```

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#embedding-arguments-into-keyword-names