# How to integrate embedded variables on RobotFramework Keywords

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework, keyword

I would like to know how to do something like this:

Resource File:

```
*** Settings ***
Library SeleniumLibrary

*** Keywords ***

Open Outdoor Menu
   Click Element  id:outdoor_menu

Check Outdoor Monitor Specs
    Page Should Contain Element  id:outdoorpossible

Check Monitors Specs
    [Arguments]   ${Menu}
    Open ${Menu} Menu
    Check ${Menu} Monitor Specs
```

I have different ${Menu} monitors and something like this would be really helpful.
So my test would be like this:

```
...
Test Template   Check Monitors Specs

*** Test Cases ***
Outdoor Menu  Outdoor
Station Menu  Station
etc.
```

I try this and gives me this error : " no keyword with name 'Open ${Menu} Menu' found. "
Do you have any ideas on how can i implement something like this?
Many thanks

Comment: Did you read this: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#embedding-arguments-into-keyword-name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I specify arguments in the middle of the sentence in gherkin-style tests in robot framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44844567/how-can-i-specify-arguments-in-the-middle-of-the-sentence-in-gherkin-style-tests)

Comment: Could it be, that you forgot the extra spaces for this keyword? Open | ${Menu} | Menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use "Run Keyword"

```
Check Monitors Specs
   [Arguments]   ${Menu}
   Run Keyword  Open ${Menu} Menu   
   Run Keyword  Check ${Menu} Monitor Specs
```